# Can a backup created on a 32bit installation be restored onto a 64bit system after upgrade?

Tags: backup, restore

Can a backup created on a 32bit installation be restored onto a 64bit system after upgrade?

I'm using Deja Dup as a backup with the default settings (basically the Home folder). I don't have any "special" folders but would like to maintain the email history and settings (Thunderbird).

Comment: What sort of backup? Are you cloning the entire system, or just backing up your files? 32Bit 'clone' should work on 64bit architecture, but not visa versa

Comment: I'm using Deja Dup as a backup with the default settings (basically the Home folder). I don't have any "special" folders but would like to maintain the email history and settings (Thunderbird).

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what you have to backed up.
Anything that is just data, i.e. music, pictures, textfiles (configuration files) and movies can be restored without a problem. 
Executables (anything in `/bin` `/sbin` `/usr/bin` `/usr/sbin` and some other places) are not usable from a backup in general. This shouldn't pose a problem, though because the programs you have installed can simply be installed again.

Comment: Thanks for that info, I am going to give it a try soon, I have tried Ubuntu 11.10 64bit version using Wubi in the Windows Partition on my laptop and it works but wanted to up the RAM to 4GiB and I was concerned it might be too much hassle to do the whole job and replace the 32bit version I normally use.